# For what security reasons are svgs blocked in the media uploader?

Tags: media, security, svg

I see that SVGs are blocked by default in the media uploader and you have to add it as a supported MIME type in functions.php. What security reasons are behind this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[SVG can contain JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Scripting). JavaScript can be used to [hijack cookies or do other questionable actions](http://blog.guya.net/2014/02/17/svg-for-fun-and-phishing/). It can even be "hidden" in namespaces:

```
<html xmlns:ø="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <ø:script src="//0x.lv/" />
</html>
```

*[source](http://maliciousmarkup.blogspot.de/2008/11/svg-and-more-xml-fun.html)*

It is very hard to filter that out during the upload, so it is just not allowed by default.

Comment: I thought the point of namespacing was to avoid tag name collision, meaning `ø:script` shouldn't be handled as `script` and thus should do nothing. What causes the namespaced `ø:script` tag to be treated as a non-namespaced `script` tag? Or do SVGs also allow embedding non-JS XML parsers?

Comment: @JAB the namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` makes this script instance an equivalent of a regular script.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. The implicit namespace for HTML tags is `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`, so you can create a reference to that URL and use it as a namespace prefix for such tags and XHTML parsers will handle them as normal tags.